# Rails delete link JavaScript ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an ajax delete call. When the link is clicked, the confirm box should appear and then the p tag fades out (comment). The problem is just how the ajax call should be and how to show the confirm box.

HTML view:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Er du sikker?" class="softdelete" href="/blogs/5/comments/18">slet</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.softdelete').click(function () {
        var Url = $(this).attr('href');
        var Data = $(this).attr('data-method');
        $(this).closest('p').fadeOut(1000);
        $.post(Url);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When clicked on the delete link, the comment fades out, but it is not destroyed. Also no confirm box appeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a `post` request, so the action isn't properly routed: Rails expects a `delete` request.

Here is the way to proceed with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: your_url,
  type: 'DELETE',
  success: function(result) {
    // Do something with the result
  }
});
```

Comment: How to show the Confirm box? And is there not a shortcut for a delete request like post?

Comment: there are countless ways to create a dialog box, it really depends on what you expect. I don't know any shortcut for the delete method.

Comment: what about the built in javascript dialag box in Rails? Is it not possible to call it?