# Can javascript listen for the result of a confirm dialogue from a separate method?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I know that the usual JS way of taking an action only if a confirmation dialog is to have the confirmation inside the function, like this jQuery example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#dropdown").change(function () {
      var success = confirm('Are you sure want to change the Dropdown ????');

      if (success == true) {
        // do something                  
      }
      else {
        // Cancel the change event and keep the selected element
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This doesn't work in my case, because the confirmation is part of a Rails helper:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'delete', :id => @item.id},
  {:method => :post, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :class => "start_spinner"} %>
```

I want to run some javascript on click (hide the link to prevent clicking twice), but only if the confirmation is true. Unfortunately, at least in Rails 2.3.x, it's not possible to use `:onclick` when the `:method` or `:confirm` options are present. (This behavior is noted [on ApiDock for the link_to helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to#955--confirm-popup-and-method-override-onclick) and is the same in my application.)

**EDIT:**
I think I created some confusion by including the example from ApiDock instead of my exact code. Sorry about that. I've modified the code below to reflect the behavior that Rails has when the `:method => :post` option is included, as it must be in my code. The difference between the two outputs is still just dropping the `destroyJsFunction` method, but there's a whole bunch of other stuff that does happen in the `onclick` that seems to interfere with implementing the solutions suggested by Sukima and agnoster.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'delete', :id => @item.id}, :method => :post, :confirm=>"Are you sure?", :onclick=>"destroyJsFunction()", :class => "start_spinner" %>
# expected output
# => <a href="/foo/delete/1" class='start_spinner' onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href;var s = document.createElement('input'); s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); s.setAttribute('value', 'CSRF_TOKEN'); f.appendChild(s);f.submit(); }; {destroyJsFunction()}; return false;">Delete</a>
# actual output
# => <a href="/foo/delete/1" class='start_spinner' onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href;var s = document.createElement('input'); s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); s.setAttribute('value', 'CSRF_TOKEN'); f.appendChild(s);f.submit(); }; return false;">Delete</a>
```

**END EDIT**

Because I'm using Rails to submit the `POST` request, I can't just re-write the link in plain HTML.

I'd like to run my javascript on click of a link with the class `start_spinner`, but I can't find a way to re-display the link if the confirmation is false. Is there a way to have a separate javascript listen for the results of a confirmation dialogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All confirm does is place some JavaScript in the HTML which does exactly what you describe: prompt the user and then submit the form on a success response.

If you want to do something different then you will have to write your own confirm method. Since the logic is so simple I'm sure the rails team felt if you wanted more you could write it yourself.

Make a function that does the confirm and if/else logic. I'd use my own unobtrusive JS like using jQuery to attach a click event but you could also use the rails link_to helper option `:onclick` like you mentioned above (I personally detest this option.)

jQuery Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.destroy').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el      = $(this);
    var response = confirm($el.data('confirm') || 'Are you sure?');

    if (!response) { return; }

    $el.css({'pointer-events': 'none'});

    $.ajax({
      url:  $el.attr('href'),
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: {_method: 'delete'}
    })
    .then(function() {
      alert('Deleted! we should do something here');
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert('Opps, it didn\'t delete, check the respose to see why.');
    })
    .always(function() {
      $el.css({'pointer-events': 'auto'});
    });
  });

  // Only for SO example not needed for real code
  $('#reset').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').css({'pointer-events': 'auto'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/path/with/:id" class="destroy" data-confirm="Are your sure?">Confirm?</a>
(<a href="#" id="reset" title="this is not need in real code">reset</a>)
```

Comment: Ah, this revision works for me! Thank you! I just had to edit the ajax options slightly; you wrote `method` where you meant `type`. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. Also added the `_method` param as some browsers don't handle the DELETE type correctly.

Comment: Works and thanks. But having `data-confirm` means Rails UJS would trigger its own confirm, resulting in two confirms. Is that your case?

Comment: @lulalala then use a different attribute name or just use UJS (whatever that is) there is nothing special about the choice of `data-confirm` other then the code above references it. Call it `data-lalala-confirm` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: kind of, sort of, but it's a little hacky.

So you want to know if the clicking of the link was confirmed or not. The only way to tell from elsewhere (without being able to inject a callback, which it sounds like would be a Rails issue) is to capture the event and check if the default action was prevented (which is what `return confirm()` is doing here).

Using jQuery you could add some JS to the page like so:

```
$('#confirm-link').click(function(e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    alert("I feel rejected")
  } else {
    alert("I feel confirmed")
  }
})
```

I twiddled with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xjbmaz9/1/). It'll be a little brittle, though.

Comment: That said, @Sukima's approach of just skipping Rails altogether is nice if you can do it, but it sounds like you need Rails to do the submit. I'm not sure how that's hooked in, though - is it also an on-click listener or something?

Comment: Rails uses the standard form submission for all actions except DELETE which will usually be done via AJAX as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9234330/227176) suggests.

Comment: Sukima: right, but it triggers the form off the link click. So... there has to be another listener or something, right? How does it work? Eh, I'm not really a Rails person, it's all a little too magic for me. If your approach works, and doesn't interfere with any assumptions Rails makes, I'd prefer it. The advantage of my solution is it works regardless of Rails's implementation quirks. :-) (Beyond of course relying on the preventDefault, but we can see that pretty plainly)

Comment: according to [this blog post](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) a `link_to` with a confirm adds a whole slew of ugly JS in the onclick attribute of the tag which ultimately returns false to prevent the actual click. When the user does confirm it builds a form with hidden input tags and appends them to the DOM only to have it trigger the hidden forms submit. So that means no you can not "hook" into it but instead need to recreate it in your own JS like I answered above.

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger the delete link as an Ajax call, then you can render a `js.erb` file that can handle the display after you confirm the dialog.  For example:

AJAX trigger in the view:

```
<li id="post_<%= post.id %>">
  <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to remove this post?" }, remote: true %>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
# app/controller/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
  end
end
```

Rendered view:

```
# app/views/posts/destroy.js.erb
$('#post_<%= @post.id %>').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails UJS's `data-confirm` and want to run some custom script based on whether the confirm was true or not, use the `confirm:complete` [event](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/9e805c90c8cfc57b39967052e1e9013ccb318cf8/src/rails.js#L294):

```
= link_to "#", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn-remove" do
```

JS:

```
$('.list').on('confirm:complete', '.btn-remove', function removeCallback(ev, answer) {
  if (answer) { 
    // Remove some element
  }
  return false; // prevents jumping to top of page.
});
```